# When I have many commits in feature_branch, How to resolve rebasing conflicts with develop branch in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, rebase

I got conflicts When I try to rebase feature_branch with develop in android studio. When I resolve those conflicts again another set of files comes up with conflicts. This is happening because feature_branch has many commits.

Can someone suggest to rebase feature_branch to develop in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Git accomplishes rebase by creating new commits and applying them to the specified base. The branch is composed of entirely new commits.

You can minimize the new commits by running git rebase with the -i flag. Instead of blindly moving all of the commits to the new base, interactive rebasing gives you the opportunity to alter individual commits in the process. This lets you clean up history by removing, splitting, and altering an existing series of a commit.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase

Answer (score 0):

First step to do before rebasing is to squash all commits to one final new commit. you can do this using `git rebase -i HEAD~N` where N is the number of commits you have in the current branch.

After this, you can easily rebase with a develop branch with easy conflicts.

This method may lose the commit history of the current branch as we are squashing all commits to one. If you want to save the history of the current branch then create new branch from the current branch before doing rebase as mentioned in the first point.